# Does Sentinel work against creatures who can avoid Opportunity Attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack

Sentinel states:

> Creatures within 5 feet of you provoke opportunity attacks from you even if they take the Disengage action before leaving your reach.

Does this mean any creature at any time leaving your reach provokes an opportunity attack (including if they take Disengage?) If so, then abilities like the following would still trigger an Opportunity Attack:

- Flyby
- Swashbuckler Rogue's Fancy Footwork (SCAG, 135)

  > During your turn , if you make a melee attack against a creature, that creature can't make opportunity attacks against you for the rest of your turn.
- Mobile Feat (PHB, Chapter 5)

  > When you make a melee attack against a creature, you don't provoke opportunity attacks from that creature for the rest of the turn, whether you hit or not.

There may be others, but the crux of the question is if Sentinel guarantees an OA.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The feat specifically calls out the case of the moving creature taking the Disengage action. A creature using Flyby or Mobile does not take such an action, but simply does not provoke an AoO. Thus using such an ability "trumps" the feat. In contrast, if an ability would let you to take Disengage as a bonus action (such as the Rogue's Cunning Action feature), it could not get around Sentinel.

Jeremy Crawford also supports this [here](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/674056205849899008). (Thanks to NautArch for the link.)

Comment: This is my initial assumption, but I wasn't sure if the limiter was to call out Disengage specifically to make sure it's clear it always happens, **or** if that's the only OA-avoidance technique that Sentinel disrupts.

Comment: @NautArch If someone knows of the designers stating what their intention was beyond what is in the PHB, feel free to correct me :) I know not of such a statement. Until then we gotta stick with the PHB and I find it reasonable.

Comment: Nitpick: There are no free actions in 5e.